# $(document).on(...) is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Somewhy line

```
$(document).on(eventType, handler);
```

throws an error

```
TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
```

What is done incorrectly?

**PS:** If that helps I'm including jquery lib with the following line

```
<script src="src/libs/jquery-1.6.1.js"> </script>
```

Comment: Check path of your jquery file again!

Comment: `on` function introduce with jquery-1.7+ version

Comment: 1.6.1 is almost 2 years old. There have been 11 updates since then...

Comment: @zerkms if every developer should first read the documentation before writing some code down, we wouldn't have developers nor programming at all.

Comment: @JoseFaeti And if every developer would read the documentation when they run into problems, we'd have 90% less content on Stackoverflow

Comment: And in the world where a crap content is better than no content it could work.

Comment: @Jose Faeti: actually reading is what every *normal* developer does before doing job. You won't go to a dentist who didn't read and learn how to cure teeth, will you?

Comment: @zerkms That's not a valid comparison. A developer **cannot know everything about every language**. Otherwise, StackOverflow wouldn't exist?

Comment: @everyone I'm not here for a flaming war, and you're right about reading the documentation first. I just didn't like the way zerkms wrote the comment in bold and uppercase letters, I don't think it's the best way to say what he wanted to say. *back to reading docs*

Comment: @mattytommo: yes, cannot. But if you apply a function and it doesn't work. Isn't it obvious for you to read the docs? For me it is. Is it that hard to get? "Otherwise, StackOverflow wouldn't exist?" --- it doesn't justify RTFM-like questions, which caused by laziness of the OP and nothing else?

Comment: @zerkms I completely agree with that, but the same could be said for about half of the questions on StackOverflow (they can be answered simply by googling). Without all of these questions, StackOverflow wouldn't be half as active. I agree with your logic, I just don't think we should be as forceful telling people to *go and do something else* :)

Comment: @mattytommo: if we won't - OP will continue asking the stupid questions. I'm here to help people who care, and to help people solving real challenges. And I'm sure answerers here expect something more, but not pointing the OPs to the straight manual pages. PS: probably I'm expecting too much and some people really are just too slow to understand single manual page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was only included in jQuery 1.7 and above. For an alternative, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (or if it's possible, upgrade your jQuery).

Example of delegate:

```
$("table").delegate("td", "click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("chosen");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `on()` was added in version 1.7. [Please see here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

So either choose another way of doing what you need to do, or upgrade your version of jQuery.

From the jQuery website:

```
For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live().
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

It doesn't exist before jQuery 1.7